# How to stop Visual Studio Code keeps from replacing double quotes with singles quotes in JavaScript?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code keeps replacing double quotes with singles quotes in my JavaScript file I am using with p5.js.

I have uninstalled Prettier - Code formatter, and I have set Prettier:JSX Single Quote to Enabled, and Prettier: Single Quote to Enabled, following someone else's instructions.  Nothing has worked.

Why is this happening and how can I change it?

Comment: Visualstudio does it for a reason: double quotes are oftentimes substitutable. Do you have any reason to require double quotes except your own will. Otherwise, I recommend you to accept VS suggestion

Comment: you uninstalled the prettier extension... so why would you try to change prettier settings? How are those settings even still displaying for you if you uninstalled the extension that contributes them? Or do you have some other Prettier extension installed?

Answer (score 1):

Check your `javascript.preferences.quoteStyle` setting. If it's set to `single`, change it to `auto` or `double`.

Comment: For others: `Ctrl + ,` is the shortcut to the preferences.